# woocommerce sort products by in stock and out of stock in front-end

Tags: wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I want to show in stock products first in products category or if possible in any where and then I want to display out of stock products too after them in Woocommerce

Actually there are many products which have not quantity number but those are in stock, So it is need to check in stock status, But I prefer to have more quantities first

How can I make a force for current sorting in such case?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using this code:

```
<?php

/**
 * Order product collections by stock status, instock products first.
 */
class iWC_Orderby_Stock_Status
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Check if WooCommerce is active
        if (in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))) {
            add_filter('posts_clauses', array($this, 'order_by_stock_status'), 2000, 2);
        }
    }

    public function order_by_stock_status($posts_clauses, $wp_query)
    {
        global $wpdb;
        // only change query on WooCommerce loops
        if (false === is_admin() && $wp_query->is_post_type_archive('product')) {
            $posts_clauses['join'] .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta istockstatus ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = istockstatus.post_id) ";
            $posts_clauses['orderby'] = " istockstatus.meta_value ASC, " . $posts_clauses['orderby'];
            $posts_clauses['where'] = " AND istockstatus.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND istockstatus.meta_value <> '' " . $posts_clauses['where'];
        }
        return $posts_clauses;
    }
}

new iWC_Orderby_Stock_Status;

?>
```

Comment: This class works like a charm when I comment the condition $wp_query->is_post_type_archive('product'). I have replaced it by is_tax("product_cat")

Comment: @Farhad Sakhaei, I'm beginner and want to know where I have to put this class ?

Comment: @MohamedAliSamali You can add it in your theme's functions.php files

Comment: @Farhad Sakhaei: without any changes ?

Comment: @MohamedAliSamali Without any change

Answer (score 0):

Others code that i saw in search sometimes can To be created 404 error in shop page, i edited to this:

```
    add_filter('posts_clauses', 'avn_order_by_stock_status');
        function avn_order_by_stock_status($posts_clauses) {
            global $wpdb;
            if (is_woocommerce() && (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_product_taxonomy())) {
                if(is_shop()){
                    $posts_clauses['join'] .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta istockstatus ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = istockstatus.post_id) ";
                }
                $posts_clauses['orderby'] = " istockstatus.meta_value ASC, " . $posts_clauses['orderby'];
                $posts_clauses['where'] = " AND istockstatus.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND istockstatus.meta_value <> '' " . $posts_clauses['where'];
            }
        return $posts_clauses;
    }
```