# Wordpress do not display the latest entries widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, widget, storefront

Some pages of Woocommerce shop do not display the latest entries widget "NEWS".

For example, on [product pages](https://kotyara.com.ua/product/uvlazhnitel-vozduha-usb-ponchik/), the "NEWS" block is normally displayed in the right column. Also on [manually created pages](https://kotyara.com.ua/vozvrat-i-obmen/).

However, there is no block "NEWS" on the [main page](https://kotyara.com.ua/) of the store and in the [categories of goods](https://kotyara.com.ua/product-category/raznoe/)...

I have spent a lot of time to find the cause, so I am hope for your help.

The latest versions of Wordpress, Woocommerce, PHP are installed. And child theme Storefront.

The widget of the latest entries "NEWS" should be displayed on all pages. Tell me, please, how to do this?

Comment: Now I know that problem caused by [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40490026/woocommerce-sort-products-by-in-stock-and-out-of-stock-in-front-end?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Now I know that problem caused by [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40490026/woocommerce-sort-products-by-in-stock-and-out-of-stock-in-front-end?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Maybe its author @farhad-sakhaei can resolve this problem.